# Project crashing at self.window line in Objective-C in Xcode 11

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, appdelegate

I have been using .storyboard file and corresponding .h and .m files to show a simple barcode scanner in my application.

What is the issue behind this?

Comment: Pay close attention to the error message: your `AppDelegate` class does not have a `setWindow` method - why?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to launch new project without a storyboard >= iOS 13 in Xcode 11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58655903/how-to-launch-new-project-without-a-storyboard-ios-13-in-xcode-11)

Comment: Could you also show `AppDelegate.h`

Answer (score 1):

try creating new reference from UIWindow.

```
`- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
CGRect windowFrame = UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds;
UIWindow *theWindow = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:windowFrame];
UIViewController *viewController = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
theWindow.rootViewController = viewController;
[self setWindow:theWindow];
return YES;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use SceneDelegate class

```
@implementation SceneDelegate

- (void)scene:(UIScene *)scene willConnectToSession:(UISceneSession *)session options:(UISceneConnectionOptions *)connectionOptions {

self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithWindowScene:(UIWindowScene *)scene];
UIViewController *vc = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:vc];
self.window.rootViewController = nav;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```