# Multiple storyboard files with scene delegate iOS 13

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ipad

I've just implemented SceneDelegate to my old iOS project which has two storyboards - `iPhone.storyboard` and `iPad.storyboard`.
There are both `AppDelegate.swift` and `SceneDelegate.swift` files without specific codes - just empty delegate methods.

[image: info.plist file]

The problem is that I have to change the storyboard name whenever I run with different device types - iPhone or iPad. My questions is how I can set multiple storyboard names to `Application Scene Manifest` section of `info.plist` file. It obviously runs with `iPad.Storyboard` file when I run with iPhone simulator for now.

P.S. I've already set `Main storyboard file base name` and `Main storyboard file base name (iPad)` values with `iPhone` and `iPad`.

Answer (score 6):

I had this problem, what you need to do is add a new scene configuration in the info.plist. I used the default one to load a storyboard for iPhones, and added a new configuration to load my iPad storyboard.

[image]

Change 'Enable Multiple Windows' to 'YES'

Then in the AppDelegate.swift -

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, configurationForConnecting connectingSceneSession: UISceneSession, options: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) -> UISceneConfiguration {
    // Called when a new scene session is being created.
    // Use this method to select a configuration to create the new scene with.
    
    var config = "Default Configuration"
    
    if IS_IPAD {
        print("IPAD - LOADING IPAD CONFIG - \(config)")
        config = "ipad Configuration"
    }
    print("LOADING CONFIG - \(config)")
    
    return UISceneConfiguration(name: config, sessionRole: connectingSceneSession.role)
}
```

This solved it for me, I hope this helps people.

Answer (score -1):

The only variant that I found for now is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58655903/how-to-launch-new-project-without-a-storyboard-ios-13-in-xcode-11) where setting different storyboards are done in SceneDelegate. Not at the info.plist.